# How can I calculate the perpendicular bisector of a vector?

Tags: vectors, bisection

I have seen questions and examples on how to calculate this which returns an equation, but how would I then apply this equation to calculate the actual vector of the perpendicular bisector?

In my example, I have two points `A` and `B`. I have calculated a directional vector from this, and found its midpoint, but how would I calculate the bisector which will give me the vector?

[image: Example]

Above is an example of what I'd like to achieve and the vector I'm looking to calculate is `C`

This is also being applied in three-dimensional space so it's important that the direction is correct.

---

Following Mohammad Riazi-Kermani example, I have produced a small example in my application which doesn't produce correct results.

Attempt

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cs1m.png)

This doesn't seem to display the correct bisector I am looking for despite the results being accurate?

```
Vector3 AB = B - A;
Vector3 midpoint = currentPoint + (AB / 2);
Vector3 V = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
Vector3 W = midpoint + (0 * V);
```

I have calculated the bisector using the above, where 0 is `t`, or the step along the vector. I have then drawn the vector from the midpoint which is displayed as a red line. The values for the bisector are

```
bisector: (3.0, 1.0, 5.0)
```

Which from the example given seems to be correct but is not drawn correctly.

Comment: In in the plane $(a,b)$ is perpendicular to $(b,-a)$. In more dimensions if your vector is $v$, you need to find the solutions, $w$, of $v\cdot w=0$.

Comment: @jyre how does this allow me to calculate `C` in my example image?

Comment: You have $A-B=(a,b)$ and were looking for a vector perpendicular to it. $(b,-a)$ is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $A =(a_1, a_2)$ and $B=(b_1, b_2)$, then $$M= \frac {1}{2} (A+B)= (\frac {1}{2} (a_1+ b_1),   \frac {1}{2} (a_2+ b_2))    $$ is the midpoint.

The direction vector of your perpendicular bisector is perpendicular to the vector AB.

Thus it if $\vec {AB} = (b_1 -a_1,b_2 -a_2) $ the direction vector of the bisector is $\vec V=(a_2 -b_2,b_1 -a_1)$

The  equation of the perpendicular  bisector is then   $$ \vec W=M+t\vec V$$

For example,

$A=(1,3,4)$, $B= (5,-1,6)$

$M=(3,1,5)$, $\vec {AB}=<4,-4,2>$

$\vec V = <1,1,0>$

$$ W=M+t\vec V = (3,1,5)+ t <1,1,0>= <3+t,1+t,5>$$

That is $$x=3+t\\y=1+t\\z=5$$

Comment: Thanks for this, is there any chance you could provide an example with three-dimensional vectors as that's what I'm working with. Does the same principle apply?

Comment: I will add an example to my solution.

Comment: What is `t`? Sorry I am unfamiliar with this.

Comment: t is a parameter which could be any real number. For every t, you get a point on your perpendicular bisector.  M is the midpoint and is the average of A and B.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense, and last thing, how did you calculate the $\vec V$ as `a2-b2` doesn't seem to give me the first value in your example.

Comment: This is in three dimension and the $a_2-b_2$ does not work. You just fine a vector whose dot product with $\vec {AB}$ is 0. Here you have many choices because in three dimension you have a plane of perpendicular bisectors.

Comment: I see. Is there any method to `find` this vector in a timely manner or is it just through brute-force? I am using this calculation in a real-time application so being able to find this vector as fast as possible is crucial.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working correctly unless I am doing it wrong? I have updated my OP to include the example.

Answer (score 2):

Given: $A=[x_1,y_1]$ and $B=[x_2,y_2]$

**1-** Calculate the *midpoint* (as you already did)
$$Midpoint = [\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2},\frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}] = [x_3,y_3]$$

**2-** Calculate the *slope*
$$Slope = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$

**3-** Calculate the *negative reciprocal* of the *slope*
$$NegativeReciprocal = \frac{-1}{slope}$$

**4-** Given the *negative reciprocal* and the *midpoint*, derive the equation for the perpendicular bisector

$midpoint = [x_3,y_3]$

$NewSlope = NegativeReciprocal = \frac{-1}{slope}$

Perpendicular Bisector Equation
$$y = m * x + b$$
$$y = NewSlope * x + b$$

Where $b = y_3 - NewSlope * x_3$

Comment: Despite the lack of [true math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), this is a nice write-up.  I would suggest adding a few words about the case where `slope` is zero, so that the perpendicular bisector is vertical.

Comment: This looks like how to plot a point on a graph, or draw on a graph. How does this apply in three-dimensional space? What is the actual vector of the bisector?

Answer (score 0):

We have that

- midpoint $M=\frac{A+B}2$

then we need to find a perpendicular vector $\vec v$ by dot product that is

- $\vec v \cdot (B-A) =0$

For example, in $\mathbb{R^3}$, if vector $\vec{AB}=B-A=(1,2,3)$ we can find a perpendicular vector $v=(a,b,c)$ by solving $\vec v \cdot \vec {AB}=a+2b+3c=0$ thus we can find infinitely many solution as for example $\vec v=(1,1,-1)$ wich is perpendicular to $\vec {AB}$.

Then the parametric equation of a bisector is given by: $M+t\vec v$.

Comment: I believe this is where I am struggling. This is all the information I have to work with. How would I go about finding this vector? I assume that once I've found it I can then cross product to find `C`?

Comment: @jjmcc for example if vector $\vec{AB}=B-A=(1,2,3)$ we can find a perpendicular vector $v=(a,b,c)$ by solving $\vec v \cdot \vec {AB}=a+2b+3c=0$ thus we can find infinitely many solution as for example $\vec v=(1,1,-1)$ wich is perpendicular to $\vec {AB}$.

Comment: @amWhy why not? it's a well known relation for vectors!